# How to view a Drone secret using the CLI?

Tags: drone.io

I want to see what the value is of a drone secret. Is there any way to view drone secrets using the drone CLI? I don't want to see it using `echo "$secret"` in the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the Drone CLI to see a secret's value once it has been set.

Comment: can i atleast check the size or last updated date of secret ?any information to confirm that i successfully updated the secret.

Comment: Neither is provided by the drone CLI - you could open an issue with the project to add that information, last updated in particular seems useful.

Answer (score 1):

Can use a Telegram bot to send drone secrets to a channel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There's no public methods (API/CLI) to retrieve secret values.

However, Drone stores its secrets unencrypted in the database, in hex encoding. If you are a server admin, you can retrieve them.